# And sign & in shell command in R

Tags: r, shell

I want to download several csv-files from the web, for example this one:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EOAN.DE?period1=1559634947&period2=1591257347&interval=1d&events=history
I want to do this in R and usually I use the command `shell` for this.

So I used the code `shell("start https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EOAN.DE?period1=1559634947&period2=1591257347&interval=1d&events=history")`

But this is the page that I reached:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EOAN.DE?period1=1559634947

It's exactly the same link but only up to the first occurence of `&`. Is there a way to tell the function that it should use the whole link? I tried to use another default browser and I tried to use `system` and `system2` but this didn't work, too.

Comment: the value for `period1` is different from the initial link

Comment: You may want to use `download.file()` for this

Comment: Also, if you keep using `shell()`,it might be necessary to additionally wrap the url in single quotes, so that the shell knows that the url is a string, Special characters can have different meanings in the shell

Comment: Oh forget about that, it was the same, actually. Will fix it.
`download.file` is great, thank you very much! A long ago that I used this function the last time, didn't think of it. 
I will use this function!
Did you think of `shell("start 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EOAN.DE?period1=1559634947&period2=1591257347&interval=1d&events=history'")`. I already tried this but it did not work. Do you mean culry single quotes?